# How to pass arguments from cmd file to a php script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have php script, that take some arguments from command line.
Something like:

```
php script.php user create
```

I need to create windows cmd file, that will call my php script, and it will pass arguments to php script.

I need to call it like:

```
command.cmd user create
```

Command.cmd source now:

```
php script.php
```

What I need to add, to send undefined number of arguments from cmd file to php script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using parameters in batch files at DOS command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286457/using-parameters-in-batch-files-at-dos-command-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `%*` at the end of the command line:

```
php script.php %*
```

This forwards all the command line arguments of the batch file to the script.

For reference, doing `CALL /?` from the command line shows (among others):

> %* in a batch script refers to all the arguments (e.g. %1 %2 %3 %4
>   %5 ...)