# How can I populate Liquibase parameter values from an external properties file?

Tags: java, maven, liquibase

Is there any way that I can populate [parameters](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html) in a Liquibase changelog file based on the contents of an external property file?

As in, I would like to be able to say:

```
<createTable tableName="${table.name}">
     <column name="id" type="int"/>
     <column name="${column1.name}" type="varchar(${column1.length})"/>
     <column name="${column2.name}" type="int"/>
</createTable>
```

And keep the value of `table.name` and the other parameters in an external file `db.properties`, and reference this file either from within the changelog, or from the Liquibase command line, or as an option of the Maven plugin that runs liquibase.

I can't seem to find any way to do this, is it possible?

Comment: what would be the solution if I want to populate the liquibase parameter from the POM properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do that at compile time:
sounds like job for maven [filters](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) and/or [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

NOTE: be carefull with liquibase and any "marker" replacements... liquibase stores CRC of applied changessets

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <filters>
            <filter>src/main/filters/liquibase.properties</filter>
        </filters>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>liquibase.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

/src/main/filters/liquibase.properties

```
table.name=TABLE_NAME
column1.name=COLUMN1_NAME
column1.length=10
column2.name=COLUMN2_NAME
```

/src/main/resources/liquibase.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog logicalFilePath="liquibase.xml" xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">

    <changeSet author="me" id="changeSetId1">
        <comment>Test</comment>

        <createTable tableName="${table.name}">
            <column name="id" type="int" />
            <column name="${column1.name}" type="varchar(${column1.length})" />
            <column name="${column2.name}" type="int" />
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

EDIT: A [typical](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/) invocation (using [filtered](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_filter_resource_files) resources) would look like this:
`mvn resources:resources liquibase:update`
or more preferably use profiles...
`mvn resources:resources liquibase:update -P<profile_name>`

EDIT2: There is one big advantage of this way of defining columns. You could use this property's (e.g.: column1.length) value (e.g.: 10) for validation of **every** layer: Hibernate, DAO, WEB, faces, JavaScript. Just use this property at each place where you need to validate against it. Even in i18n/messages.properties if needed (e.g.: input1.validation=No more than ${column1.length} letters.).

The only complication is that if you need to change this value you need to provide proper liquibase update/rollback script. Sometimes it is possible to change value and set new liquibase checksum (safe operation like increase varchar length), but other times you need to create a *safe* update changescript using new property/value.

Comment: Hi Wooff! I'm trying to use the same structure but I'm getting an error when I run liquibase:update - 'table.name' in properties file is not being used by this task.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [here](http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/change-log-parameters-for-custom-sql-changesets). You can either use a command line arguments (`-D[arg name]=[arg value]`) or environment variables.
If you don't use any build manager tool such as Maven or Ant you will need to write a script for reading parameters from file and passing them to the command. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298769/1051509)

Comment: Can Maven dynamically build the command line from a properties file, defining all -Dname=value pairs automatically for liquibase?