# How to store more than 9 parameters using windows Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a piece of code that uses variable Parameter to store the inputs from the users. For example:

Code:

```
@echo off
set Parameter=%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
findstr "%Parameter%" abc.txt > new1.txt
```

This works perfectly fine.

But if I change the parameter line to the below line
set Parameter=%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 %10 %11 %12 %13 %14, then it causes a problem.

I understand more than 9 parameters are not accepted. Please can you provide any solution for this. I am not sure how shift can be used in this.

Comment: Possible Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286457/using-parameters-in-batch-files-at-dos-command-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET /a paramcount=1
:paramloop
SET "param%paramcount%=%1"
IF DEFINED param%paramcount% SET /a paramcount+=1&shift&GOTO paramloop
SET /a paramcount -=1

SET param

GOTO :EOF
```

This should allow you to do whatever you want with parameters.

Comment: +1 comperatively robust , but if you pass this `"&rem&param1"` as argument will fail :)

Answer (score 2):

This is all you need:

```
findstr "%*" abc.txt > new1.txt
```

or this:

```
@echo off
set Parameter=%*
findstr "%Parameter%" abc.txt > new1.txt
```

This assumes that the quotes are appropriate in your situation.

Comment: Thanks @npocmaka  :)  A bit more info there now.

Comment: Thanks :) can it be modified to only pick 3 or more input parameters i.e from %3 to more, as I want %1, %2 to be stored for some other thing, not in Parameter.

Comment: That's a different question.  Open a new question - they are free. SO is arranged around one question per item.

Answer (score 1):

There is, of course, no `%10`, this will just output `%1` with a 0 on the end of it. However, you can use `%*` which will return all input.

This uses a for loop tho echo all input -

```
For %%a in (%*) do echo %%a
```

You can adapt this to do what you are trying to do -

```
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
set Parameter=
For %%a in (%*) do set Parameter=!Parameter! %%a
findstr "!Parameter:~1!" abc.txt > new1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

another option is to use [SHIFT](http://ss64.com/nt/shift.html):

```
@echo off
set /A param=1

:argParser
        echo parameter-%param% %~1
        shift
        set /A param=%param% + 1
        if "%1" EQU "" (
            echo all parameters have been echoed
            goto :endArgParser
        )

goto :argParser
:endArgParser
```

though will fail if some of the parameters breaks the `IF` syntax eq `equ"`