# Batch file variable substitution

Tags: batch-file

I was trying this (very rudimentary) command in a batch file

```
takeown.exe /F c:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\%1%
ICACLS C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\%1% /grant MY\PC:F
```

And when I run it from an admin CMD prompt as:

```
c:\Data>takeownscript.bat drivers\netbio.sys
```

It throws an error saying:

> c:\Data>takeown.exe /F c:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\drivers\netio.sys
>
> SUCCESS: The file (or folder): "c:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\drivers\**netio.sys**"
>   now owned by user "MY\PC".
>
> c:\Data>ICACLS C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\drivers\**netio.sysF**
>   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\drivers\**netio.sysF**: The system cannot find the
>   file specified. Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1
>   files

How/why is the F getting appended to the driver path ? I am suspecting that I am not using the correct replacement syntax.

Comment: Arguments of the batch file should be referenced using `%1`, and not `%1%` as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286457/using-parameters-in-batch-files-at-dos-command-line).

Comment: @Laf that works. Please consider this query solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to finish up so the community knows there is an answer.

---

Command-line arguments are used as `%n`(`n` represents which argument) in a batch file.

Another thing for precaution is that one should use `%~1` at all times. `%~1` strips off quotes from `%1`. Note that this won't work: `%~yourVariable%`.