# Check parameter is set in any position in a Windows Batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Within a Windows Batch script, how can I check if a given parameter is set in any position? For example, say I called `myscript.bat`, as follows:

```
myscript.bat /foo /bar
```

I want to determine if `/foo` is set I could do:

```
if "%1" == "/foo" echo "/foo is set"
```

But say now I call the script as follows:

```
myscript.bat /bar /foo
```

The above code no longer echos `/foo is set`.

How can I write an `if` condition such that is true whether `/foo` is in any position? Does Windows Batch provide a simple way of doing this without having to check every parameter in a for loop?

Comment: I may be able to do this by using a substring search against all the parameters using `%*` and the techniques described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005951/batch-file-find-if-substring-is-in-string-not-in-a-file

Comment: Considering your rep score and that you're not a new member, I was wondering why your question shows no effort at having tackled the issue yourself. I'm also interested to know why you have limited advice to solutions using `If` and not using `For`.

Comment: Take a look at the tread [Using parameters in batch files at Windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14286457), particularly the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298769), to learn about a possible way to solve your issue…

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. Perhaps this is the simplest one:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Set elements of "argv" array variable
for %%a in (%*) do set "argv[%%a]=1"

rem Check for a given switch
if defined argv[/foo] echo /foo is set
```

You may extend this method in this way:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Set elements of "argv" array variable
set "n=0"
for %%a in (%*) do set /A "n+=1, argv[%%a]=n"

rem Check for a given switch and its position
if defined argv[/foo] echo /foo is set at position %argv[/foo]%
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give a real example of why you need to get confirmation of the argument.

However this not so good example will work after a fashion without for and one if

```
@echo off & set foo=
echo "%*" | find "/foo" && set foo=found
if "%foo%" equ "found" echo "/foo is set"
```