# Why shorthand notation of calling .bat file doesn't work in PhpStorm's console

Tags: powershell, batch-file, terminal, phpstorm, windows-11

I am using PHP and Yii Framework, so I need to call `php yii` with each command. To make this just a little bit more handy, following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298769/1469208), I have created `run.bat` file, with this content:

```
@echo off
php yii %*
```

I have placed it in `%SystemRoot%` (`c:\WINDOWS\`), so it is accessible system wide, from any path.

To my extreme surprise I have found the following:

1. **Command-line** (Terminal in Windows 11): Both `run` and `run.bat` works just fine.
2. **Windows PowerShell**: Both `run` and `run.bat` works just fine.
3. **Terminal inside PhpStorm**: Must use `run.bat` because `run` doesn't work:

[image]

In the same time both `php` and `yii` works in PhpStorm like I charm and I am not forced to execute `php.exe` or `yii.bat`.

What am I missing? What changes should I introduce to file content or file location (or maybe `PATH` system variable) to be able to use just `run` in PhpStorm?

Comment: Does the same command works if you launch **the same** terminal outside of PhpStorm? Just in case: in PhpStorm you seems to be using BASH and not CMD or PS. And each shell will have own rules deciding what file is executable when file extension is omitted. (`echo %PATHEXT%` in CMD will show what file extensions are used and in what order when you try to execute your `run` without `.bat`)

Comment: Regardless of the location of `php.exe` and `yii.bat` you should still use their full paths, and extensions: ```@"%~dp0php.exe" "%~dp0..\htdocs\yii\framework\yii.bat" %*```. It is almost always prudent to explicitly define the working directory at the outset of your scripts, _(this allows for you to use relative locations if you prefer)_. You should never rely upon `%PATH%` or `%PATHEXT%`, being preset with your required content, _(doing so also adds a time overhead)_. I'd have to ask why you aren't using `yiic.bat`, which is the console interface script.

Comment: @Compo The below works, so I still don't see the reason for putting full paths. I am not relying on `%PATH%` in anywhere. If there will be no path to `php.exe` executable defined then nothing will work, both my scripts and `php yii` call. The `yiic` is a PHP script from versio 1.1 of Yii Framework. It was replaced with `yii` in version 2.0. I am using it directly. As in question -- my script is just an shorthand to call `y` instead of `php yii` as so far. Nothing else. The `yii` script is still responsible for all the magic here. I am not changing this in any way.

Comment: If you use what's in the current answer, you are still relying on `%PATHEXT%`, and you explained in the body text, item 1.  that `%PATH%` is relied upon!

Comment: Sorry, but I am too newbie to this topic, so I still don't understand your point of view. In my system `%PATHEXT%` includes extensions only (no paths). While it truly has `.cmd` listed, in my approach I am not using this extension. I am executing `y` command which calls `y` file, not `y.cmd`.

Comment: Plus, your approach with full paths (`\htdocs\yii\framework\yii.bat`) won't work at all, because Yii 2.0 uses Composer and is deployed with every project instead of residing in one pre-fixed path or location. I can call my shorthand `y` from any path in my system, but it will work only in folders containing a Yii 2 project. Because only there you have `yii` script deployed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments and [this article](https://onezeronull.com/2023/11/20/shorthand-notation-for-yii-commands-in-git-bash-and-windows-terminal/) the correct resolution is to:

1. Pick a folder listed in `%PATH%` system variable (`C:\XAMPP\php` in my case).
2. Put a file named i.e. `y.cmd` in this folder with the following content:

```bash
@php.exe yii %*
```

3. Put a file named i.e. `y` in the same folder with the following content:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
php.exe yii $@
```

That should be all. Starting from this point it should be possible to call both `y` and `y.cmd` from any location in given system and with using *cmd* command-line, Windows Terminal, Git Bash (including PhpStorm) etc.

BTW: There is no path for `php.exe` in above scripts, because both `y` and `y.cmd` scripts as good as `php.exe` file are placed in the same folder. If these files are put in separate folders then using full paths is necessary.