# Passing parametric input parameter to batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, command-line-arguments

This might be a simple question, but I didn't found any thread, may be I am searching wrong.

I am having a simple bat script and passing some arguments. Currently I am getting the argument based on there order. But I want to make simple for the user.

My current command line looks like: `testBatch.bat setupip setupuser setuppass`
My current batch script looks like:

```
set setupip=%1
set setupuser=%2
set setuppass=%3
echo I am doing some operation after this based on the input I got.
```

Now I want to modify the command such that the user should not be woried about the order of argument to pass. Basically I want to see my command like this: `testBatch.bat --ip setupip --user setupuser --password setuppass`

**What modification I have to do in my batch script?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to pass parameters "by name" (and not by order) to a batch .bat file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215729/is-there-a-way-to-pass-parameters-by-name-and-not-by-order-to-a-batch-bat-f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
@echo off


for %%a in (%*) do (
    call set "%%~1=%%~2"
    shift
)

echo :%--user%
echo :%--pass%
```

if the passed it is called like:

```
namedArgs.bat --user user --pass pass
```

the output will be like:

> :user
>
> :pass

This will handle also quoted parameters with spaces in them.

Comment: so simple and effective! Thanks so much

Answer (score 4):

Thing you are looking for is called 'Named Arguments'. I found link for same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215729/is-there-a-way-to-pass-parameters-by-name-and-not-by-order-to-a-batch-bat-f).

Answer Which I like from that link is as follow:

```
set c=defaultC
set s=defaultS
set u=defaultU

:initial
if "%1"=="" goto done
echo              %1
set aux=%1
if "%aux:~0,1%"=="-" (
   set nome=%aux:~1,250%
) else (
   set "%nome%=%1"
   set nome=
)
shift
goto initial
:done

echo %c%
echo %s%
echo %u%
```

Run the following command:

```
arguments.bat -c users -u products
```

Will generate the following output:

```
users
defaultS
products
```

Comment: Don't post link only answer.

Comment: Added code snippet from link where I do refered the answer. @PetterFriberg

Answer (score 1):

There is a batch command called `shift`, which can basically do a shift left on your parameter variables.

So as the start of your script, you need a loop

inside that loop you decode %1 for the 'verb' part of your option with a `if` statement

inside that `if` block, you call `shift`.  then old `%2` becomes the new`%1`, old `%3` becomes the new `%2`, etc

so inside that if, you can pick up a secondary argument for the verb, if needed.  Then call `shift` again.

loop until your arguments are empty.  Tadah!